# How Often Can I Crawl A Website With PHP?

Tags: php, web-crawler, bots

I wanted to build an Android App that would crawl a website with php and get information from a tiny span tag inside the website that I'm crawling.

I wanted to know is this even legal (I think it is because Google is constantly crawling websites).

I also need to know how often I can do it or even if there is a rule of this sort.

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on many factors: Whether the web site you're crawling allows it; which country you are in; which country the crawled web site is in; and what you're doing with the data

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think you're getting into the arena of web-scraping more than web crawling. The two are almost identical, but scraping "focuses more on the transformation of unstructured data on the web, typically in HTML format, into structured data that can be stored and analyzed in a central local database or spreadsheet."  And typically, there are quite a few legal issues that revolve around scraping a web site that isn't yours.

Wikipedia has a [pretty decent section on the legal issues involving scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues).

In other words, it is completely up to the owner of the site you want to crawl/scrape.

Comment: What would you say about cnbc.com (a really popular site)

Comment: It appears they don't permit it; see the second half of section 1 (Restrictions on Use) from their [ToS](http://www.cnbc.com/id/15837353/).  It begins with "You may not"...  That said, depending on how wide spread your app is, you may be able to get away with it or get permission but its something only a lawyer could advise on at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you've got 2 issues:

- How do you retrieve the data?
- Should you?

The former is relatively simple - The latter is far more complex.

From a purely technical POV, if you were to scrape a site daily, nobody is likely to notice unless it's a VERY low volume site (and they're unlikely to care).

Remember that the more often you scrape, the more server resources you'll consume.

Good nettiquette says that you should respect the wishes of the site owner. Many sites will offer alternate - approved - ways of getting data, usually through a web service.

You should attempt to comply with the restrictions specified in any `robots.txt` file (just Google it). This is also good behaviour.

Really, it depends on where you draw the line between politeness and need.

One thing to consider: Many many sources of information are happy to have their data re-used as long as they're given credit. (Although, to be fair, others are totally opposed, regardless.)

If I were in your position, I'd first try to contact the site in question and ask for permission as a courtesy - The worst they can do is say no.

The next question arrises from who *exactly* is pulling the data. If you scrape from a central server, the same IP address will be doing the queries. If the app itself pulls the data, it'll be multiple IP addresses and likely lost in the "static" unless the app behaves stupidly.